# applicationinsights.config external custom library

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I'm sure this must be easy, but I can't find any documentation on it.

I have a custom `ITelemetryChannel` implementation in another assembly.  How do I add it to the `applicationinsights.config`?  The examples in Microsoft's documentation assume the class is in the same assembly as the web application.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
<TelemetryChannel Type="Namespace.MyTelemetryChannel, OtherAssemblyName" />
```

- `Namespace.MyTelemetryChannel` should be your fully qualified type name for your class
- It should be followed by the assembly name eg. `OtherAssemblyName`

**Default ITelemetryChannel:**

The default channel used by ApplicationInsights.Web is `ServerTelemetryChannel` which is present by default in the ApplicationInsights.config file:

```
<TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel"/>
```

If you check the references in your project you'll find `Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel` is the assembly from where `ServerTelemetryChannel` is initialized.

**Initializing properties with ITelemetryChannel:**

You can also initialize properties (as long as they have public getters and setters) from the ApplicationInsights.config, as shown below:

```
<TelemetryChannel Type="Namespace.MyTelemetryChannel, OtherAssemblyName">
    <SomeCount>20</SomeCount>
</TelemetryChannel>
```

assuming your TelemetryChannel includes the property `SomeCount`:

```
public class MyTelemetryChannel: ITelemetryChannel
{
    public int SomeCount { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps!